# Not able to remove 'sharing' for a folder already shared?

Tags: networking, permissions, samba, shared-folders

I have been using Ubuntu in my machine since 3+ years. I found a folder ('Videos' from 'Home' directory) is shared on network. I don't remember when did I do it? Now, I want to remove it from being shared.

When I checked the `folder sharing options`, there is no 'tick' on `share the folder`.

The 'Videos' folder is shared it on network. How to remove the sharing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two places where share definitions are held depending on how you created the share:

[1] In **/etc/samba/smb.conf** itself. Just edit that file and remove the share definition. THen restart smbd: `sudo service smbd restart`

[2] In **/var/lib/samba/usershares**. If you did it this way there is a file for every share that you created from your file manager. Deleting the file removes the share.

Comment: Second option worked.

Comment: First option worked.